# Offline site/application to propagate a form

Tags: html, forms, offline

We are building an offline version of our online store.
This is for reps to take with them on a tablet when they are out. The reason it needs to be offline is because there will be no connection in a lot of the places and we aren't using tablets with 3/4g connectivity.We use Windows 8.1/RT based tablets.

Since php relies on a server and the tablets cannot be installed with xampp or the like, I have rebuilt the site using html and css.

So far this works and has some flexibility in it. The website is turned into an application using googles create application button in its tools (though technically it's not really an application). It has all the product info, pictures and videos the reps need. Another advantage to this is that the application and files are stored on a one drive cloud account shared to all the tablets. This way, I can update the app/website from my machine and have it up to date on all the reps machines. This current set up works for now but we are looking to add some more functionality.

What we want is a button on each product that will let a rep add an amount of that particular product to a quote form. Because each product sits on a different page, it can't be in the one page form. So as the rep is pressing the buttons on each product, they are getting stored somewhere. Then at the end, the rep can turn all those values into a word doc/pdf/excel by hitting a final submit button.

I have looked at web storage in html 5 but still not quite sure if I can get what I need using it.
Going through the explination here:
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html 
looks like sites can store info but not sure how to turn this into a form or document at the end. This document is what the reps will email back to the head office.

Has anyone got any pointers on what I could do. Since the site/app has been created in html already, I would like to just build into the existing framework. Are there any other pieces of software that I could use? I do remember using spreadsheet converter to turn an excel file into a web form that exported a pdf but the form needs to be on a single page.

All help appreciated.

Thanks